# Is sum of infinite many compact sets closed?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, compactness

Consider a sequence of compact sets $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$, where $S_i \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $0\in S_i$ for all $i$. Define

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty S_k := \Big\{\sum_{k = 1}^\infty s_k \;\;  \Big| \;\; \text{ this sum exists and } s_k \in S_k \;\; \forall k\Big\}$$

How to show that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty S_k$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n$?

---

Here is what I tried.

Define $S:= \sum_{k = 1}^\infty S_k$.

I want to prove it by contradiction. So suppose there exists a vector $s \notin S$ but there exists a sequence of $\{s_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}, s_i \in S$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = s$.

Since $s_i \in S$, then there exists a sequence $z_{ij} \in S_j, j=1, 2, \cdots$, such that $\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^m z_{ij} = s_i$. Then $s = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^m z_{nj}$.

Then I want to use the interchange of these two limits but I do not know **which theorem I should refer to.**

If I use the interchange directly, I can get $s = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^m \lim\limits_{m \to \infty}  z_{nj} = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^m  z_j$, where $z_j \in S_j$ since $S_j$ is compact. Then $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{j=1}^m  z_j \in S$, which forms a contradiction.

---

But the problem is I do not know if I can use the interchange of two limits.

Comment: Is it fair to assume that $S_i$ are sets of real or complex numbers or something like that? And could it be that when you write $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ you mean $\bigcup_{n}$?

Comment: Re-edit. Thanks. It is not a union and please see the definition in the bracket about the sum of two sets.

Comment: I am not asking about the sum, that is fine, I was wondering what you mean by the limit of a sequence of sets?

Comment: That's $S_1 + S_2 + \cdots + S_n + \cdots$.

Comment: I'm confused about the $\forall$ in the definition of $S_i + S_j$. Also, I think you want to write your space as $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty S_k = \{\sum_{k = 1}^\infty s_k \;\;|\;\; s_k \in S_k \forall k\}$ (with the added restriction that all such sums must converge). Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, that is true.

Comment: If you mean to consider the set that consists of elements $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i$ for arbitrary $n$, that would be $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i = 1}^n S_i$. If you mean something else, please explain. Note that without a proper definition of limit, even sums like $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \dots$ do not have any meaning.

Comment: It's a set contains all limiting points in the form $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} s_i, s_i \in S_i$.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote to reopen, but I vote to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Counterexample: $n=1$,
$$S_i = \{0, 1+ 1/i\}$$
for each $i=1, 2,\cdots$.

Then $1$ is a limit point of $\sum S_i$ since $1+1/i\in \sum S_i$, but $1$ is not in it: every points in $\sum S_i$ is either
$$ 0 = 0+ 0 + \cdots +$$
or is $>1$ (when one of $s_i \neq 0$).

Comment: We assume $S_i$ is compact and I think for this example, 1 should belong to $S_i$ ?

Comment: This is not an interval, @oneuser $S_i$ has only two elements $0$ and $1+ \frac{1}{i}$.

Comment: We have a sequence of $S_i$ , what if the $i$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: $S_i$ is not a sequence. It is a set.... (which parts of the answer that I wrote do you not understand?) @oneuser

Comment: Sorry about my mistakes. I got it. Thanks!  By the way, if I add a condition that $S_i = S_j, \forall i \neq j$, it seems $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}S_i$ is closed? is there any general way to prove?

Comment: I am not completely sure, @oneuser even for your current question my initial guess was that it is true...

Comment: Actually, we can give a counterexample showing that it is false even $S_i = S_j, \forall i \neq j$.

Comment: @oneuser What is the example?

Answer (score -3):

Assume $n = 1$. Let $\mathbf S = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty S_k$. Take a sequence $\mathbf x_1, ..., \mathbf x_n$ in $\mathbf S$. We must show that the limit point of that sequence is in $\mathbf S$. Wlog assume $\mathbf x_1 \le \mathbf x_2 \le \cdots$ (this is easy to justify). For each $\mathbf x_i$, let $(s_{i,1}, s_{i,2}, ...)$ be such that $s_{i,k} \in S_k$ for all $k$, and $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty s_{i,k} = \mathbf x_i$.

**Claim.** We can construct the $\mathbf x_i$ from underlying summands that are monotonically increasing across the sequence $\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, ...$ -- formally, there are elements $(s'_{1,1}, s'_{1,2}, ...)$, $(s'_{2,1}, s'_{2,2}, ...)$ such that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty s_{i,k} = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty s'_{i,k} = \mathbf x_i$ for all $i$, and $s'_{1,i} \le s'_{2,i} \le s'_{3,i} \le \cdots $ for all $i$. (I'm not going to prove this here, but I'm pretty confident it's true -- think about it.)

Given this, we can construct the summands $s^*_1, s^*_2, ...$ with $s^*_k \in S_k$ of the limit point $\mathbf x^*$ in the obvious way. Namely, $s_j^* := \lim_{k = 1}^\infty s'_{k,j}$. We know this limit point exists because the $s'_{k,j}$ are monotonically increasing and $S_j$ is compact.

By construction, $\mathbf x^* \in \mathbf S$. All that's left to prove is that $\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, \cdots$ does, in fact, converge to $\mathbf x^*$. I'm also not doing this, but I'm about 90% confident that it's true. I think you need to assume something like, there is a sequence $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, ... $ with $\epsilon_i \in \mathbb R$ and $\lim_{i = 1}^\infty \epsilon_i = 0$ and $S_k \subseteq [-\epsilon_k, \epsilon_k]$. You can assume this without loss of gneerality because if it isn't true, then $\mathbf S = \mathbb R$ so the problem is trivial.

If all that is correct, you still have to extend it to $n > 1$, but I think the core ideas are here.

Comment: So $x^* = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Comment: yeah that's what I meant by saying that $\mathbf x_1, \mathbf x_2, ...$ converges to $\mathbf x^*$.

Comment: What's the difference between $x_i$ and $s_i^*$ in your definitions?

Comment: $\mathbf x_i$ is an infinite sum of elements and lives in the space $\mathbf S$, which is why I wrote it in bold. $s^*_i = \lim_{j = 1}^\infty s'_{j,i}$ and as such lives in $S_i$. I think you need to read the post more carefully; the definitions are all there.

Comment: I think you use the interchange of two limits. Since $x^* = \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} s_{n, k}$, and you use $\lim_{m\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}  \lim_{n\to \infty} s_{n, k} = \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} s_k^* = x^*$. But why we can interchange the limits.

Comment: Forget exchanging limits. I first construct the $s^*_j$. Each $s^*_j$ is precisely defined and can be shown to live in $S_j$. Then, I take those and defined another limit with them. At no point I was thinking about double limits here. (I haven't thought deeply enough about your comment to understand how it maps onto my argument, but I don't think it's needed.)

Comment: Also, I think your expectations are a bit unreasonable. At the very least, you should have put enough effort into your submission to format it as cleanly as it is after my edit. If you had done this, it probably wouldn't have been closed.